# Getting all combinations in a 2d array

Tags: java, arrays, recursion, 2d

I am given an int array with numbers that I need to list all their combos in a 2d array.

For example if im given an int array of `(1,2)` the combos would be 
`(0,1) (1,0) (1,2) (0,2) (1,1)`

i need to put these in a 2d array, like:

```
(0,1)
(1,0)
(1,2)
```

and so on....
why is my code not working? any suggestions?

```
public static int[][] getCombinations(int[] choices) {

    int size = choices.length;

    int combos = 0;

    int[][] options = new int [size][combos];


    if (size == 1) {
        options[combos][0] = 1;      
    }else {

        for (int j = 0; j < size; j++) {

            choices[j] = j -1;              
            getCombinations(choices);                
            choices[j] = j+1;
        } 
    } 
    return options;
}
```

Comment: These are primitives, so isn’t the array size fixed when it’s made?And you saying 0 columns which would make it empty perhaps?

Comment: i changed options to null, still not working!

Comment: Why does 0 show in your combos if it's not in the initial array? Why is (1,1) valid but not (2,2)?

Comment: Change it to like 500. Then see how it works, and you might get the picture better. The issue is this. When you make your array, you have to tell it how many things its going to hold. This can never be changed. You need to tell it how to big to be. You told it to take on size 0 the first time, which is pointless... The second time you used null, which is also pointless. Give it a real number.